# Error message on sending a mailing, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE

Tags: mailing

Any ideas what is causing this when we try to send out a mailing?

```
("DB Error: syntax error", 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civicrm_temp_group_contact_cache495 (SELECT 25 as grou...") #4
```

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73

Comment: First of all it will help us if you add your CiviCRM version and CMS. Do you have any customization in your CiviCRM installation?

Comment: No serious customisations. Version 4.7.22.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I saw something like this was when custom fields on a table had been added, a group had been created using these custom fields and subsequently the custom fields had physically been deleted. This meant the custom group cache table failed to create - the group used in the mailing was the culprit. I'd try using a different group as a test. If it works then look to rebuild your smart group - the full error in the SQL should point you in the right direction.